# how to create a string with special characters

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to create the following variable:

```
login_string <- '{"identifier":"wallaby", "password": "sea_dragon5"}'
```

Now, instead of storing the password in the script, I'd like the user to input the password with the following command:

```
input_password <- rstudioapi::askForPassword()
```

Then, I'm lost on how to use `input_password` and create the `login_string`.
I tried `paste0`, which did not work - `paste0("'{"identifier":"wallaby", "password": ""input_password,"}"')`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: thanks, that worked!!!!

Comment: could you put your comment as an answer so that I can close this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to separate raw text and variables by `,` in `paste0`:

```
input_password <- "random_password"
login_string <- paste0('{"identifier":"wallaby", "password":"', input_password, '"}')

cat(login_string)
# {"identifier":"wallaby", "password":"random_password"}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of the `jsonlite` to create this.  Create a named `list` and use `toJSON` to convert it to json format

```
library(jsonlite)
login_string <- toJSON(list(identifier = "wallaby", 
           password = input_password), auto_unbox = TRUE)
cat(login_string)
# {"identifier":"wallaby","password":"random_password"}
```

#### data

```
input_password <- "random_password"
```